# Centos6... PHP73x provisioning/configuration woes - anyone know why?

Tags: php

NOOOB question! I'm running CentOS 6 still - and it seems my installation got glitched, or misconfigured. First of all there were issues getting PHP7.1 in at all (IUS repo was all there was at the time).. Later uninstalled and used REMI 7.3.
This was all pretty delicate, as its a live server. Anyway, got PHP73 in, but the last couple of PHP updates (7.3.9 and 7.3.11)  have been 'hellish' in that they killed the PHP functionality of our main website entirely.

I got the error 'module php7_module is already loaded, skipping' - and with a little scrambling managed to fix it by commenting a line in php.conf as shown:

#LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so

I think this is what I edited last time an update killed things...
Should I just be deleting the php.conf entirely??

Because I also have a php73-php.conf ... which contains this:

LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp73.so

I'm wondering if it's safe to delete the other conf file (which seems to get rewritten every time there is a PHP patch!) - this seems logical but I haven't been able to google any clear confirmation of this. Can anyone enlighten me?  TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> got the error 'module php7_module is already loaded, skipping'

It looks like your installation is not correct as if you have this message, this mean you really have various module installed. Perhaps the old one from IUS and a newer one from Remi, which have SCL, i.e. version designed for parallel installation.

Edit: according to comment you have both php (mod_php as base package) and php73-php (mod_php as SCL). I recommend the remove the second.

Of course only 1 version of mod_php can be load at the same time.

A list of installed packages will help

```
rpm -qa php\* | sort
```

For a proper installation, I recommend you follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions

Comment: Thanks!  I ran that command and ALL of the output is 'proper' 7.3.11 from remi. Maybe when I uninstalled the ius, it just didn't delete ( or rename) the old php.conf file?? Or do I need to still have that php.conf file in addition to the php73-php.conf ? I actually did  use that exact wizard for the install...

Comment: PS: rpm -qa php\* | sort  gives this...

php-7.3.11-1.el6.remi.x86_64

php73-2.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64

php73-build-2.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64

php73-php-7.3.11-1.el6.remi.x86_64

php73-php-ast-1.0.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64

php73-php-bcmath-7.3.11-1.el6.remi.x86_64

php73-php-brotli-0.7.0-1.el6.remi.x86_64

php73-php-cli-7.3.11-1.el6.remi.x86_64

php73-php-common-7.3.11-1.el6.remi.x86_64

(etc etc)

Comment: ouch! cant seem to get linefeeds into the comments here.. wondering if there is a problem with the first "php-73" vs all the other "php73-php"... or if it belongs with them...

Comment: You have both php-* and php73-php-*, keep only 1 stack

Comment: Also read the repo FAQ: https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl